# INSERT more than one rows using SAVE() function - Joomla 2.5

Tags: php, joomla

I have my own `save()` function to save the Joomla form's data into DB. This is how it looks like

**Note:** I have written my own save() function because I have to save into two tables upon one save action

```
class footballModelPlayer extends JModelAdmin {
enter code here
  public function save($data) {

    $table_two = $this->getTable('player_sec_positions', 'footballTable', array());

    $player_id = $data['player_id'];

    $player_sec_positions_data = array();

    foreach ($data['sec_position_name'] as $pos_name) {
        $player_sec_positions_data['player_id'] = $player_id;

        $player_sec_positions_data['sec_position_name'] = $pos_name;

        // var_dump($player_sec_positions_data);
        $table_two->bind($player_sec_positions_data);
        $table_two->save($player_sec_positions_data);
    }

    return $data->player_id;
  }
}
```

Problem is that I cannot save more than one rows, What only this code is doing that it saves the last `array`(see below) where `sec_position_nam` is *Right*.

I want to save all rows into DB || How do enter more than one rows into DB using `save()` joomla function.

And the output of `var_dump($player_sec_positions_data)` is like this...

```
   array
  'player_id' => int 1
  'sec_position_name' => string 'Left' (length=4)

   array
  'player_id' => int 1
  'sec_position_name' => string 'Middle' (length=6)

   array
  'player_id' => int 1
  'sec_position_name' => string 'Right' (length=5)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the table inside the loop, somehing like:

```
class footballModelPlayer extends JModelAdmin
{

    public function save ($data)
    {
        foreach ($data['sec_position_name'] as $pos_name)
        {
            $table_two = $this->getTable('player_sec_positions', 'footballTable', array());

            $player_sec_positions_data = array();
            $player_sec_positions_data['player_id'] = $data['player_id'];

            $player_sec_positions_data['sec_position_name'] = $pos_name;

            // var_dump($player_sec_positions_data);
            $table_two->bind($player_sec_positions_data);
            $table_two->save($player_sec_positions_data);
        }

        return $data['player_id'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using this.

Maybe this is not a good approach.

```
$player_id = $data['player_id'];

$player_sec_positions_data = array();

$db = $this->getDBO();
$query = "INSERT INTO #__football_player_sec_positions (player_id,sec_position_name)
          VALUES ";

foreach ($data['sec_position_name'] as $pos_name) {
    $player_sec_positions_data['player_id'] = $player_id;

    $player_sec_positions_data['sec_position_name'] = $pos_name;

    $query .= "($player_id, '$pos_name'),";
}

$query = rtrim($query, ",");


$db->setQuery($query);
$db->query();
```

Comment: Did you try my solution instead of making native DB inserts?